# jquery show more/close bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I wrote up code to "Show more" / "Close" for each `div` and also when I have opened one and then already opened one close first and other open.

Problem is when I press close in same `div` it reopened it and doesn't close it. I also put in code `.not(this)`, but doesn't really work. Problem is also because scroll to function doesn't work really good.

If I am on first `div` and just little scroll to second and press close it jumps in middle of text not on top of `div` like it suppose to.

Here is jquery code:

```
    $('.cities').each(function(){
    var max = 7;
    var numLi = $(this).find('li').length;
    var list = $(this).find('li:gt(' + max + ')');
    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');

    list.hide();
    if(numLi > max){
        $(this).find('ul').append('<a class="more" name="'+id+'">Show more</a>');
    }
    $(this).find('.more').click(function(){
        // zapre vse odprte
        $('.cities').find('li:gt(' + max + ')').not(this).hide('slow');
        $('.cities .more').not(this).text('Show more');

        list.toggle('slow');
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show more' ? 'Close' : 'Show more');  

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top},'slow');
    }); 
});
```

And also working example http://jsfiddle.net/B2MXD/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slideToggle()`.

```
$('.more').click(function(){
var max = 7;
    $(this).closest("ul").find('li:gt(' + max + ')').slideToggle();
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show more' ? 'Close' : 'Show more');  
});
```

You dont have to loop through each element to bind events. Simply use `$('.more').` to bind events to all the elements with class name`more`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/B2MXD/3/)

**Edit**

```
$('.more').click(function(){
var max = 7;
    $('.more').not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).closest("ul").find('li:gt(' + max + ')').slideUp();
        $(this).text('Show more'); 
    });
    $(this).closest("ul").find('li:gt(' + max + ')').slideToggle();
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show more' ? 'Close' : 'Show more');  
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B2MXD/5/)

Comment: How can i do that all opened just closes and exactly clicked has to be showen or close. Also i thing i still needs to go throught each, because if they are only 4 elements i dont need more button..

Comment: Like it is in my code, if they are only 4 elements of li dont append show more/close, if they are 8 append show more/close.